# Get particular value from json array in java

Tags: java, json

Code is written in java

```
JSONArray resultArray = (JSONArray)resultObject;
String str = (resultArray.get(0).toString())
```

Now I have a string which is as follows

```
{
    "styleId": "2276730",
    "price": "$199.95",
    "originalPrice": "$199.95",
    "colorId": "401",
    "productName": "Mutiny",
    "productId": "8149427",
    "percentOff": "0%"
},
```

I want to have the value of price for each such array

I am a newbie to JSON. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The example "JSON" you've provided isn't an array (it's an object) and it's not even a _valid_ object, because of the extra trailing comma. Please provide a **complete** example which reproduces the exact problem.

Comment: He said it's an item of JSONArray

Comment: You shouldn't do toString until you have the object you want (if then).  Assuming the original is a JSONArray, `get` the element by number, cast the result to JSONObject, and then do `get("price")` on that.  This should directly return a String containing the price.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray resultArray = (JSONArray) resultObject;
for (int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject result = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(result.getString("price"));
}
```

Comment: JSONObject result = array.getJSONObject(i); can I know what is array referring to here??

Comment: It was a typo, I've corrected it. Of course it should be `resultArray`

Comment: Yes.I too thought it was resultArray but when I am running the code, the ide is not identifyingthe getJSONObject method. I checked the imports but of no use. The method getString is also not being recognized. I ran the code and the error indicates the same.

Comment: Did you add "import org.json.JSONObject;" and "import org.json.JSONArray;" at the header of your file? `getString` is a valid method of JSONObject http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Note that there are two entirely different and distinct JSON kits that use "JSONObject" and "JSONArray".

Comment: yep, javax.json and org.json. But both ot them have these methods with identical signature.